# What happens if a tubeless tyre is overinflated?

Tags: tubeless, tire-pressure

The gravelking [SK](https://www.panaracer.co.uk/shop-c1/tyres-c34/gravel-tyres-c2/panaracer-gravel-king-sk-tlc-folding-tyre-p49) has a max tubeless pressure of 60 psi.

What happens if you inflate it more, to say 100?

Comment: Try it out! (Wear hearing projection)

Comment: I don't mean enough to blow the tyre off the rim. I mean what will happen when riding it. 100 psi is not close to enough to blow the tyre off the rim - give it a try. Hearing protection optional.

Comment: Depends on the rim, which likely has its own max pressure. But if you don't think the tire or rim will fail at 100 psi, then what are you actually asking about?

Comment: @PaulH before trying it out, consider that blowing off the rim will damage the rubber where the rim meets the tyre.  So even at normal pressures it may not seat properly ever again.  Be prepared that might write-off the tyre.

Comment: Actual question aside here, but why would you ever need to know?  I 100% realise tyre pressure has an element of personal preference but inflating it to that high just seems a little beyond realistic.  Unless of course you are purely asking from a theoretical out of interest point of view.

Answer (score 5):

Even with tubes, the tyre is what withstands the force. Tubeless of course has some unique failure modes but there will also be common ones.

A dodgy pressure gauge meant I put what I later worked out to be about 110psi in a tyre rated up to 80. After 1-2km (about a mile) it sounded like the tyre was rubbing on the V-brakes. It was actually the tube, through a split that had opened up in the sidewall. I stopped, but before I could get off a huge split opened up in the tyre, parallel to the bead but not right next to it, and the tube burst.

Translating that to tubeless, I suggest one possible outcome is that you blow out your sidewall, probably where there's already a little scratch forming a weak point. It's going to be messy with sealant flying around.

Comment: From 2023 onwards: If you think about something, there is a youtube video about it:
*"We blew it! Inflating a tubeless bike tire until it fails catastrophically"*
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8eNcqqvVyxI

Comment: @EarlGrey it's a shame none of the many cameras was pointing at the pressure gauge.  But that clearly blew the tyre off the rim, which is certainly a plausible failure mode

Answer (score 2):

The exact same things may happen as when you overinflate a tubed tire:

- If the rim's side wall is weak (too much rim braking), the side wall may fail by bending outwards, releasing the tire's bead with a loud bang.
- If the tire's bead is weak, the tire may jump off the rim with a loud bang. Not likely to happen if the tire was well-seated.
- If the tire's side wall is weak (riding with too little pressure), the side wall may tear apart, again with the result of a loud bang.

None of these failure modes depends in any way on the presence of a tube. And which failure happens first depends on the make and history of the rim and the tire. Most dangerous is the brake induced failure mode because the brake that damaged the rim will also immediately stop the rotation of the wheel when the deformed metal meets the brake.

Answer (score 1):

With tubeless tires, I think you shouldn't need to overinflate them to seat them. What counts is the blast of air into the chamber. With wider tires, there is another potential reason. The larger the tire, the [more tension the casing is under](https://blog.flocycling.com/gravel-wheels/flo-gravel-wheel-design-journey-part-4-casing-tension-study-with-union-university/) for the same pressure. If you're talking a proper gravel-sized tire, there is a lot of force pressing outwards. I worry about the possibility that either the casing or the rim might get damaged.

If you have a carbon hookless wheel, then the maximum rated pressure is 72 PSI. I was under the impression, after several Cyclingtips podcasts on tubeless tire design, that there may not be a big safety factor built in here. Nevertheless, if you are in this situation, that increases the downside quite a bit.

Comment: "If you have a carbon hookless wheel, then the maximum rated pressure is 72 PSI" is this a universal truth for all carbon hookless wheels?

Comment: @MaplePanda it is part of the new ISO standard. So yes, I suspect it is practically universal, although it’s totally possible that someone built in larger than usual safety margins.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware such a standard came into existence! I learn something new every day.

Comment: @MaplePanda some more reading here by an old Cyclingtips writer, but note that this may be behind a metered paywall https://velo.outsideonline.com/road/road-racing/an-endless-faq-to-tubeless/

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually an Outside+ subscriber. Legacy perk from being an early subscriber to the Trailforks mapping service :)